Send Emails using the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Email in C#
I am sending Email from My C# code to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Email But it's giving me Following Error

Error: "The server response was: Authentication required|Inner Exception"

Following is my Code
try
{
    // Retrieve SMTP configuration from web.config
    string smtpHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPHost"];
    int smtpPort = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"]);
    string senderEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"];
    string senderID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderUser"];
    string senderPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPwd"];

    // Define the recipient, subject, and body of the email
    string recipientEmail = "akki@gmail.com";
    string subject = "Test Email From New Details";
    string body = "This is a test email sent from ASP.NET MVC.";

    // Create a new MailMessage object
    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(senderEmail);
        mail.To.Add(recipientEmail);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        // Create a new SmtpClient object
        using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, smtpPort))
        {
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            //smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);
            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword);
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true; // Ensure this matches the server's SSL requirements

            // Send the email
            smtpClient.Send(mail);
            //ViewBag.Message = "Email sent successfully!";
        }
    }
}
catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
{
    // Log SMTP specific errors
    //ViewBag.Message = $"SMTP Exception: {smtpEx.Message}";
    Console.WriteLine(smtpEx.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Log general errors
    //ViewBag.Message = $"General Exception: {ex.Message}";
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

I want to send email from my code but it giving me above error, I search but not recevied anything from net for C#

Are you able to send emails using another SMTP client (for example, Thunderbird)?

i have able to send normal mail but not oracle configuration mail

What does "oracle configuration mail" mean? Are you using the SAME smtp settings in your third party client as you are in C#?

i am using this 


Can anyone here help me on this??
